# Choose the column having more data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have to select a column out of two columns which has more data or values in it using PySpark and keep it in my DataFrame.

For example, we have two columns A and B:

[image]

In example, the column B has more values so I will keep it in my DF for transformations. Similarly, I would take A, if A had more values. I think we can do it using `if else` conditions, but I'm not able to get the correct logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a data frame with the data

   ```
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(1,7),(2,4),(3,7),(4,8),(5,0),(6,0),(None,3),(None,5),(None,8),(None,4)],schema = ['A','B'])
   ```
2. Define a condition to check for that

   ```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    import pyspark.sql.functions as fx

    condition = fx.when((fx.col('A').isNotNull() & (fx.col('A')>fx.col('B'))),fx.col('A')).otherwise(fx.col('B'))
    df_1 = df.withColumn('max_value_among_A_and_B',condition)
   ```
3. Print the dataframe

   ```
   df_1.show()
   ```

Please check the below screenshot for details

[image]

or

If you want to pick up the whole column just based on the count. you can try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as fx

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(1,7),(2,4),(3,7),(4,8),(5,0),(6,0),(None,3),(None,5),(None,8),(None,4)],schema = ['A','B'])

if df.select('A').count() > df.select('B').count():
    pickcolumn = 'A'
else:
    pickcolumn = 'B'

df_1 = df.withColumn('NewColumnm',col(pickcolumn)).drop('A','B')
df_1.show()
```

[image]

Comment: i don't want to create a new column, just want to keep only one of them.

Comment: Then you can drop columns A and B and then rename the max_value column

Answer (score 2):

You could first aggregate the columns (`count` the values in each). This way you will get just 1 row which you could extract as dictionary using `.head().asDict()`. Then use Python's `max(your_dict, key=your_dict.get)` to get the dict's key having the max value (i.e. the name of the column which has maximum number of values). Then just `select` this column.

Example input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 7), (2, 4), (3, 7), (None, 8), (None, 4)], ['A', 'B'])
df.show()
# +----+---+
# |   A|  B|
# +----+---+
# |   1|  7|
# |   2|  4|
# |   3|  7|
# |null|  8|
# |null|  4|
# +----+---+
```

Scalable script using built-in `max`:

```py
val_cnt = df.agg(*[F.count(c).alias(c) for c in {'A', 'B'}]).head().asDict()
df = df.select(max(val_cnt, key=val_cnt.get))

df.show()
# +---+
# |  B|
# +---+
# |  7|
# |  4|
# |  7|
# |  8|
# |  4|
# +---+
```

Script for just 2 columns (A and B):

```py
head = df.agg(*[F.count(c).alias(c) for c in {'A', 'B'}]).head()
df = df.select('B' if head.B > head.A else 'A')

df.show()
# +---+
# |  B|
# +---+
# |  7|
# |  4|
# |  7|
# |  8|
# |  4|
# +---+
```

Scalable script adjustable to more columns, without built-in `max`:

```py
val_cnt = df.agg(*[F.count(c).alias(c) for c in {'A', 'B'}]).head().asDict()
key, val = '', -1
for k, v in val_cnt.items():
    if v > val:
        key, val = k, v
df = df.select(key)

df.show()
# +---+
# |  B|
# +---+
# |  7|
# |  4|
# |  7|
# |  8|
# |  4|
# +---+
```

Comment: Hi , your code is working fine one small change we need to use builtins library here.. builtins.max to get the result. Without builtins its is giving error max got an unexpected error

Comment: @DataWorld - Thanks for the feedback. I have added a couple more options to make the answer more extensive.